# JAXB marshalling creates namespaces prefixes in random order each time

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

sample soap message has namespace prefix like below when I marshal the request object.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.org/test1" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.org/test2" xmlns:ns1=
  "http://schemas.org/test3" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

next time order changes to,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.org/test2" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.org/test3" xmlns:ns1=
  "http://schemas.org/test1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

and so on...

Though my request body updates with the new namespaces each time, there is an issue where the project consuming my code expects the prefixes to be in the first order. Is there a way to control this and if so what would be an example?